# Teleport unknown amount of players to a specific area

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm making a server full of mini-games, and I'm running into small problems on specific games. I got everything set up except for this issue:

In racing games, I'm having trouble teleporting the winner (or top 3, I know how to place them) to a "podium": I don't know how to let the game know how many players there are, and teleport the winners into one area and everybody else into another.

Comment: On my phone so I can’t test this but you could probably do something like `/execute if score` for the second part of your question.  Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/MinecraftCommands/comments/918tz0/comment/e2xek05

Comment: @TwentyCharMax Incorrect. You are linking to Java-Edition specific articles. This question is for Minecraft Bedrock Edition.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure how to fix the first problem but the second one can be solved by using `/tag (Insert target selector for winning players) add Winners` and then using `/tp @a [tag=!Winners] <x,y,z>` to teleport the rest of the players. `/tag` gives a specific data tag to players or entities that helps specify who you want your commands to affect.